# Move a record from one table to another laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've a list of users , where admin can approve or deny.Maintain two tables if admin clicks "approve" a user,the records 'ld **move** from that table to another table.How can I achieve this?
In view,

```
<span>
    <a href="{!! route('approve', ['id' => $user->id]) !!}">
        Approve
    </a>
</span> <br/>
```

In `route`,

```
<?php 

Route::get(
            'approve/{id}', 
            [ 'uses' => 'DriverController@postApprove', 'as' => 'approve' ] 
           );

?>
```

In `controller`,

```
<?php

public function postApprove( $id )
{
 **?**
}

?>
```

Comment: Add more information about `the recors 'ld move from that table to another table` !!

Comment: When I click approve button that user information 'ld move to a new table

Comment: Ok with just this information i can answer like this : find the user in the first table with the id = $id then create a record and save it in the second table finlly remove the user fom the first table !! ok with that ??

Comment: Why not just have an "approved" flag on one table instead of having two tables that hold the same type of entity?

Comment: @Maraboc I've three tables One is for  " approvedusers" another one is for "declinedusers".Another new table has the records of all "users" ,When admin clicks approve the record 'ld move from **users** to **approvedusers**.That's what I want

Comment: @apokryfos When I use approve ( has boolean  '1' or '0'),I didn't get the no of users last inserted

Comment: You can in this case use enum with three values if you want !

Comment: @apokryfos can you explain brief?

Comment: @Maraboc can you give me an example

Comment: There's many ways to get this to work without moving users around. Simplest thing is to have an `admin_action_at` column as a datetime and an `approved` column as a boolean. If the `admin_action_at` is null then the admin hasn't approved or rejected yet and if it has a date in it them the `approved` will contain the admin decision.

Comment: I agree with @apokryfos with this implementation you will have an extra information witch is the time of the aproval ;)

Comment: @apokryfos For this I'ld have field admin_action_at and when click approve button the datetime should store in the field right

Comment: Thaks.I just 'll try it

Comment: @apokryfos will you give an example to store datetime in table pls?

Comment: In laravel you'd probably do `DB::table("users")->where("id", <user id>)->update([ "admin_action_at" => Carbon::now() ])`  (it works because casting carbon to string happens to be a valid MySQL datetime format)

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks.It shows the error 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '38' in 'where clause' (SQL: update `users` set `admin_action_at` = 2017-10-25 11:52:57 where `38` is null)' But I've a that user column  in my table

Comment: `where 38 is null` looks odd. Are you sure you're executing the query correctly? It should have a `where("id",...)` in there somewhere

Comment: Now it works thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @apokryfos Is I've to do the same for ** Decline**

Comment: You can just add one field `approved` and overall do `DB::table("users")->where("id", <user id>)->update([ "admin_action_at" => Carbon::now(), "approved" => <true if approved false if not> ])`

Comment: I got it !!!!!!